# What is the relationship between BodyParser and Request => Result in Play Scala?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

In Play Scala you might have seen something like this:

```
  def index = Action.apply[RawBuffer](BodyParsers.parse.raw){ (request: Request[RawBuffer]) =>
    val body: RawBuffer = request.body
    Ok.apply(views.html.index(SharedMessages.itWorks))
  }
```

Whether the generic being used is AnyContent or JsValue of whatever.

What is the relationship between BodyParser and Request => Result in Play Scala?

*** Update ***

Where in the source code of the Play Framework is the BodyParser applied to the request? Does it use Reflection? Does the BodyParser take in Request => Result as a variable in a function. How do these two things connect in the API. The source code does not make it at all clear that request.body is making a call to BodyParsers.parse.raw

Comment: Body of `Request` is parsed with `BodyParser` and then you use it to return `Result`. I don't think your question is clear.

Comment: @Łukasz Where in the source code of the Play Framework is the BodyParser applied to the request? Does it use Reflection? Does the BodyParser take in Request => Result as a variable in a function. How do these two things connect in the API. The source code does not make it at all clear that request.body is making a call to BodyParsers.parse.raw

Comment: Just see sources https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Action.scala#L103 lines 103 and 455. It doesn't use reflection. When you are building action with `Action.apply` factory method you pass a function, `Request[BodyType] => Result` that will be executed by Play, and play will parse the content before executing your function.

Comment: @Łukasz So the body parsing happens before executing the function. And then how does request.body access the parsed body?

Comment: On line 108 `val request = Request(rh, a)` a request object with parsed body is created, and then passed to the function on line 112 `apply(request)`

Comment: @Łukasz - I'm a junior, but is the parsing happening only once and then request.body keeps returning the result or the parsing happens every time request.body is called. Does request.body have a side effect?

Comment: It is parsed once in line 103 `parser(rh)` and then it is put in new created request that I talked about in previous comment. It is parsed once and put into an object that you can access without any side effects.

Comment: @Łukasz the body is parsed once and then put in a new created request that is passed into Request[BodyType] => Result. Parsing happens before application of Request[BodyType] => Result and request.body always returns the same thing, no side effects. Got it. What if the body is HUGE - like 2 Gb (a single 2Gb mp4 file). Then would the parser parse this huge body piece-by-piece and store the whole file on disk so that request.body would point to a file in disk?

Comment: Please just see docs for details, they are quite explanatory https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaBodyParsers